# To update multiple rows using stored procedure in Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to figure out how to update a postgres table using an array of object. I want each object in the array to correspond to a new row, with each key corresponding to a column, and each value is the data to be inserted into the column.

Also would like to know how to call that procedure in c#?

Here the the data format:

```
[
    { col1: a, col2: 5, col3: 1, col4: one},
    { col1: b, col2: 6, col3: 2, col4: two},
    { col1: c, col2: 7, col3: 3, col4: three},
    { col1: d, col2: 8, col3: 4, col4: four},
]
```

Here is my expected output:

```
 col1   (varchar)| col2 (integer) |   col3 (integer)   |   col4 (varchar)
-----------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------
    a            |  5             |     1              |    one
    b            |  6             |     2              |    two
    c            |  7             |     3              |    three
    d            |  8             |     4              |    four   

 I am passing the data format as array in stored procedure.
    But want to know, how to cal the SP from c#?


The stored procedure I have written is:  

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.sp_insertorupdatereadings(d dbo.reading[])
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

begin
--Update min values
update dbo.reading set 
  p7_1_5_1_0_first =subquery.p7_1_5_1_0_first,
  p7_1_5_1_0_last =subquery.p7_1_5_1_0_last,
  p7_1_5_2_0_first=subquery.p7_1_5_2_0_first,
  p7_1_5_2_0_last=subquery.p7_1_5_2_0_last
  From (select * from unnest(d)) as subquery
  where dbo.reading.p7_1_5_1_0_first= subquery.p7_1_5_1_0_first;

-- insert new records
  insert into dbo.reading 
select * from unnest(d) as inserd where (id) not in (select id from dbo.reading);
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.reading(dbo.reading[])
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: using npgsql for postgre  https://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It would be a huge help to actually see the stored procedure and any relevant .NET objects, so most of the advice I can offer is only notional.

Unlike other ADO adapters that use the `CommandType` property of the command object, for NpgSql/PostgreSQL, you can just call the stored procedure using a select command:

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select my_stored_proc()", conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If you have parameters it follows the same pattern as any other command (select, insert, update):

```
using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select my_stored_proc(:P1, :P2)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P1", "foo");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("P2", 3.14);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You mentioned your parameter was an array...  but I don't think you can have a Postgres array of mixed datatypes, can you?  Certainly, in C# you can have an array of objects but I don't think that translates cleanly to a PostgreSQL array.

Here is an example of a parameter with an array, using an array of integers:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("NUMS", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array |
    NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3};
```

If you can add some detail to your question, perhaps I can frame the answer better.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have added the SP that I am using. Please see that. I have an object "Readings" which I have converted to an array.But you said this cannot be done with Postgres. So can I serialize the same to a JSON string then? And then split the string and use For loop in SP

Comment: That's actually a good idea.  If you pass the object as JSON, you should be able to work with it that way.  In .NET it's very easy to convert an object to JSON.  If you use the Newtonsoft.JSON package (via Nuget), the command is simply `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);`  Then you can pass that as a parameter to your Postgres procedure

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Also need to know how to use JSON string  in stored procedure?